# How can I create a Datagridview column to handle nullable bools?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, nullable

I am displaying data from SQL in a datagridview by using a SqlDataAdapter. (This is a C# Winforms app but this question could just as easily apply to VB.) Some of the columns are a nullable bool.

Currently the datagridview uses a standard CheckBox column, which uses an empty checkbox both for null and false, and a checked checkbox for true.

I would like to create a column that displays no checkbox at all for null values.

What's the best way to approach this problem? I am wondering if I should create a new control that inherits from the DataGridView and go from there.

Comment: you can look into [CheckBox.ThreeState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.threestate.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that I've employed and is currently working:

```
((DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)dgvDisplayData.Columns["field_name"]).ThreeState = true;
```

This is done after the data binding and assuming that the sql field "field_name" is a nullable boolean. Resharper isn't especially happy with this format, providing a "Possible System.NullReferenceException" warning.

I'd still be interested in alternative/better suggestions.

**Edit:**

I've changed this as follows to avoid potential null value exceptions:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chkCol =
    (DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)dgvDisplayData.Columns["field_name"];
if (chkCol != null) chkCol.ThreeState = true;
```

Comment: Since you're the OP, if you're happy with this, you should mark this as the answer, otherwise, please make sure we understand what you still need now.

Comment: It's looking like I'll have to do that. My solution is working, but as stated in the answer, I'm still interested in suggestions for a better solution (or confirmation that this is the best one).

Answer (score 1):

You could also override the DataGridView's CellPainting event to selectively *not* draw the checkbox if the value is null. I've done so on occasion in an application, like so:

```
private void MyDataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == MyCheckBoxColumn.Index && e.RowIndex >= 0) {
        var paintparts = e.PaintParts;
        if (e.Value == null) {
            paintparts &= ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground;
        }
        e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, paintparts);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This tells the grid view, that if the value of the column is null (in case of a *bool?* value like I had -- if you are using database columns you might need to compare to *DBNull.Value*, not sure about that) to not paint ContentForeground (which includes the checkbox). In all other cases, painting occurs as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably to handle this in the OnRowDatabound Eventhandler in the code behind.  You will also probably want to implement a RowUpdating event handler that will set null otherwize you are liable to end up with false being saved.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an `OnRowDatabound` nor `RowUpdating` event for a DataGridView control...

Answer (score 0):

Make a template column with a checkbox, bind the checkbox's Enabled property to your nullable bool's "HasValue" property, and bind the checkbox's checked property to `nullableBool.HasValue ? nullableBool.Value : false`